# How to add new line programmatically in CodeMirror?

Tags: codemirror

I need to insert a new line next to my current line number in CodeMirror.

I viewed the documentation but didn't find anything about appending any content at the end of the line.

Please help. :(

Answer (score 10):

Get the current line from the cursor position, and act on it. This should do it (not tested):

```js
var doc = cm.getDoc();
var cursor = doc.getCursor(); // gets the line number in the cursor position
var line = doc.getLine(cursor.line); // get the line contents
var pos = { // create a new object to avoid mutation of the original selection
    line: cursor.line,
    ch: line.length - 1 // set the character position to the end of the line
}
doc.replaceRange('my new line of code\n', pos); // adds a new line
```

Comment: Hi @eliran, Thank you for your reply. I tried the code but the text inserts at the beginning of the line.

Comment: right, i forgot about the 'end of the line' part... see the updated answer

Comment: Mutating an object returned by `getCursor` will corrupt your selection in recent versions of CodeMirror. Don't do it.

Comment: Yeah we should probably copy that first. Thanks, @Marijn. And thanks again, for CodeMirror :)

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```js
function appendTo(editor, line, text) {
    editor.replaceRange(text, CodeMirror.Pos(line));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this to add a new line `editor.replaceRange("\n", { line });`

Answer (score 1):

**To add the new line at the end -**

```
function updateCodeMirror(data){
    var cm = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;
    var doc = cm.getDoc();
    var cursor = doc.getCursor(); // gets the line number in the cursor position
    var line = doc.getLine(cursor.line); // get the line contents
    console.log(doc);
    var pos = { // create a new object to avoid mutation of the original selection
        line: (doc.size+5),
        ch: line.length - 1 // set the character position to the end of the line
    }
    doc.replaceRange('\n'+data+'\n', pos); // adds a new line
}
```

Call function

```
updateCodeMirror("This is new line");
```